# Is it possible to build POS by Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I know that Ruby on Rails is a web application framework. But Here I want to build POS(Point of Sale) system with following constraints:

1. It must connect with large database (Retail shop database)
2. It does not require any internet connection.
3. It could be either desktop application or accessed through web browser.
4. Local web server and POS both are in same system. Not ready to maintain two or more system.

Comment: Rails can easily be run on the local system without internet connection (as far as connection to database is possible, e.g. local database or database in local network). I don't see any problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, It's Possible**

This type of system is exactly what Rails is for

You'll be best researching the [mvc programming pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) (which Rails is built around). Although there are a [lot of other frameworks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_application_frameworks) which do the same thing:

[image]

This basically means you have a central data repository (can be online or not), and you access it through a series of `views` and `controllers`.

--

**Access**

The trick for you is that you can make the database locally-accessible, and give the interface an address on the local network.

You have to remember a `web server` is just a computer running software that's available from the Internet (via a public IP). What you need is to create a `local` server (which is only accessible from the [`local area network`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_area_network)), and provide a way for the other systems to access it

I would either get a crappy computer to run the Rails software (to act as a local server), or just use one of the many cloud providers who'll provide server access through the Internet. If you did this, you'll have to grant access to a particular IP only, allowing you treat the system as local

Comment: Is it require internet connection?

Comment: Not if you keep the database server in your local area network!